# How can I create tabs without a view pager

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I need three tabs that basically change the sorting on a listview below. I don't need a view pager or anything too complex but I can only find examples with a view pager. I am using appCompat and toolbar and extending AppCompatActivity.

I've tried a tab host but it's invisible when I run the app

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/tab1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="horizontal" />
...
```

Comment: "I've tried a tab host but it's invisible when I run the app" -- well, did you add any tabs? That would be in your Java code. `TabHost` certainly works, as does `FragmentTabHost`. The Design Support library has a tabs implementation as well, that while it *can* work with `ViewPager`, does not *require* `ViewPager` AFAIK. All that being said, since most tab implementations use `ViewPager`, your users may expect to be able to swipe between tabs, even if you think that you do not need it.

Comment: If you want to change the sort, why not just change the sort?  Why the need for tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want buttons, rather than tabs. But you want it to look like the new TabLayout and Application, you should be able to use the new TabLayout that is provided in the [Design Support Libraries](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), however you won't need to hook up the actions to actually page anything and can use them to trigger changing of the Sort Order.

Your Activity's Layout will have something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

In your Activity you will want something along the lines of:

```
mTabLayout = mActivity.getTabLayout();
if (mTabLayout != null) {
    // Or manually set if you want
    mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(getPagerAdapter());
    mPageChangeListener = new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout);
    // This is the bit that you will not want as that will change pages
    // and you aren't actually changing pages, just listening
    // Leaving these lines in just for reference on what you would do for paging
    // mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    //mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mPager) );
}
loadData();
```

And then you can implement the various onPage* methods, which you can use to simply trigger your Sort Order changes, rather than actually have it change pages on you.